# Form post display message

Tags: ajax, post, chat

I have a form that is posting in table without refreshing.... So i want to display instantly after post as a chat, but the problem is the form and insert code is on same page chat.php, how can i put jquery code in same page to display instantly? can someone give me an example?

Here is the form

```
    <form  id="contact-form" class="bl_form text-center" action="<?php echo "index.php?page=rooms&room=$rid&amp;rpw=$rpw&amp;r=$r"; ?>" method="post" novalidate>
                    <span class="field-wrap scrollimation fade-right">


                    </span>
                                        <span class="field-wrap scrollimation fade-left">

                        <textarea id="contact-message" name="message" rows="5" class="label_better requiredField" data-new-placeholder="Message" 

placeholder="Message" style="margin: 0px; width: 1210px; height: 88px;" data-error-empty="<?php echo "$insert_message"; ?>"></textarea>
                    </span>

                    <p class="text-center"><button  name="sy2" id="submit_post" type="submit"  class="btn btn-sm btn-primary icon-left" data-error-

message="Error!" data-sending-message="Sending..." data-ok-message="Message Sent"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Send Message</button></p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                    <?php echo "<postfield name=\"message\" value=\"$(message)\"/>"; ?>
                </form>
```

And here is the final code that displays the message that you post but not with ajax

```
<?php echo make_clickable($tosay)."$link_stergere"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a sugestion but returns me empty message,here is a print screen

[empty message screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2laFx.png)

```
    $('body').on('submit', '#contact-form', function(){
  $.post({$(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data){
    if(data){
      alert(data.message);
    }
  }, 'json');
  return false;
});
And the server side

<?php 
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    // do your thing here
    echo json_encode(array("message" => make_clickable($tosay).$link_stergere));
    die();
  }
?>
```